# How to find is this first time player registering / playing game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, ios8

How to find is this first time player registering / playing game ?
I am using GKLocalPlayer and game centre  to enter in game and ( and leaderboard to get data ) I need to know is this first time player is playing this game.

Comment: Store a bool variable with `NSUserDefaults`

Answer (score 0):

Just store a boolean locally in NSUserDefaults.

```
NSString *hasCompletedFirstLaunchKey = @"kHasCompletedFirstLaunchKey";
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults objectForKey:hasCompletedFirstLaunchKey]) {

    //first time code goes here

    //set the key to yes
    [defaults setObject:@YES forKey:hasCompletedFirstLaunchKey];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: If player change the phone I'll get new registration even if that is same game centre player ?

Comment: Using this method, yes. This would probably be fine if you were, say, just trying to decide whether or not to show the user a tutorial. If this is unacceptable, you'll need a backend solution to store, at a minimum, a list of registered players. A BaaS solution like parse.com will make this relatively straight forward.

Comment: I am using parse but I new to parse, I have PFUser in inherited code but not sure how to know if is registered or not ?

Comment: Oh nice! So, you'll want to add a new "isRegistered" (or whatever) property to your PFUser object, set it to YES, then use saveInBackground to save it to Parse. You can confirm that the data was saved properly by checking the User table. From then on, the next time that PFUser logs in, their isRegistered flag should come back to you properly set.